# Compiled same enum with maven vs. ant: Differences

Tags: java, maven, ant, enums

I compiled the same enum with Maven and Ant (Java 7). The class files differ. The order of some elements in the constant pool seems to be different and, furthermore, generated methods have different bytecode. The "values()" method looks like this for Maven:

```
public static de.continentale.vs.common.model.enums.PartnerRolle[] values();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #1                  // Field $VALUES:[Lde/continentale/vs/common/model/enums/PartnerRolle;
       3: invokevirtual #2                  // Method "[Lde/continentale/vs/common/model/enums/PartnerRolle;".clone:()Ljava/lang/Object;
       6: checkcast     #3                  // class "[Lde/continentale/vs/common/model/enums/PartnerRolle;"
       9: areturn
```

The other version (Ant) is this:

```
 public static de.continentale.vs.common.model.enums.PartnerRolle[] values();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #115                // Field ENUM$VALUES:[Lde/continentale/vs/common/model/enums/PartnerRolle;
       3: dup           
       4: astore_0      
       5: iconst_0      
       6: aload_0       
       7: arraylength   
       8: dup           
       9: istore_1      
      10: anewarray     #1                  // class de/continentale/vs/common/model/enums/PartnerRolle
      13: dup           
      14: astore_2      
      15: iconst_0      
      16: iload_1       
      17: invokestatic  #147                // Method java/lang/System.arraycopy:(Ljava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;II)V
      20: aload_2       
      21: areturn
```

This seems to happen for all enums that I compile. Any idea what happened?

Comment: Did you specify different target JVM versions? Did you use different compilers/JDK to compile?

Comment: Did they both use the exact same version of Java to compile with?

Comment: I used jdk 1.7.0_67 for both compilations. Target version is Java 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Ant correctly used the jdk 1.7.0_67, the result was influenced by the Eclipse compiler which creates class files in the background. So some of the "Ant class files" were really Eclipse class files that Ant did not build again. The Eclipse compiler produces slightly different bytecode.

Comment: could you please share the details over *was influenced by the Eclipse compiler*.. how? Also the question never read any details over the compiler, how would one link this to be a solution to the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I added the compiler version in the comment from Dec 9. Starting the Ant targets from Eclipse while "Build Automatically" was activated somehow lead to the situation that some classes where compiled with the Eclipse compiler. Deleting the target directory before starting the Ant task from the command line solved the problem.